# MongoDB Aggregate function(distinct) in c programming

Tags: c, mongodb

I want to use distinct function in users collection. In mongo shell, I
can use like the following:

```
   db.users.distinct("name");
```

where name is the collections field used to distinct.

likewise I want, the same in c code. Only the distinct part I want,
familiar with creating connections, working cursors, working bson
data. Also, the [link](http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/) having only the
basics of mongo c API.

I need the complete documentation of c api, if anyone knows give me
the link.

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you can do that using the `mongo_run_command` [function](http://api.mongodb.org/c/0.3.1/mongo_8h.html#a48a7945952a34674d7898f3c5a2d79bc), since `distinct` is a [command](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Distinct): `db.runCommand( { distinct: 'users', key: 'name' } )`